# BI Apps on 12c Pluggable Database

Tags: database, oracle, business-intelligence, obiee, rcu

Is anyone running BI apps on a 12c pluggable database? I'm running into some installation issues with the RCU when it tries to import the .dmp files to create the schemas on a pluggable database.

We have BI Apps running on 12c in another environment, but the database wasn't setup as a container database.

I'm just wondering if anyone has gotten through the install process of being able to run BI Apps on a pluggable database and haven't had any subsequent issues.

Comment: can you be specific?  what installation issues?

Comment: The RCU gives an internal error when it tries to run an import of the .dmp files:
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-39006: internal error
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 79
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_DATAPUMP", line 4087
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_DATAPUMP", line 5926
ORA-06512: at line 1

End of stack trace:
at oracle.biapps.rcu.dbinstall.DataPumpUtils.callDpOpen(DataPumpUtils.java:328)
 at oracle.biapps.rcu.dbinstall.DataPumpUtils.importSchema(DataPumpUtils.java:476)

Comment: Also getting this at the end of the Error:

2015-11-10 09:25:57.568 ERROR rcu: oracle.sysman.assistants.rcu.backend.action.AbstractAction::handleNonIgnorableError: Received Non-Ignorable Error: ORA-39006: internal error

Comment: The .dmp files are the ones the RCU comes with to create the ODI and DW schemas and populate with metadata.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the datapump utility is [not corrupted](https://community.oracle.com/thread/925398) by running this statement

```
select count(*) from metanametrans$;
```

You can reload the utility by running these from the SQL command line

```
@$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/catmet2.sql
@$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/utlrp.sql
```

Also check that adequate disk space is available.
How was the dump file transferred?  Binary mode is recommended.